# How to: allow users to create their on pages on web app?

Tags: node.js, architecture

I'm relatively new to webdev, and essentially I'm trying to create functionality that allows users to create their own event pages (similar to Facebook Events, Meetup etc.).

My question is to do with the surrounding architecture of this, namely:

1. Given each event page will have its own url, do you need a separate file for each event in the backend?
2. Or is there some clever way of templating and directing traffic? (Sorry if this is vague, I'm trying to probe if there is a better way of doing this?)
3. I notice that most of the FB/Meetup events all have their own URLs, does this mean that they all have separate files in the backend?

I'm using Nodejs for the backend btw.

I've been Googling around but haven't been able to figure it out, I think I might be using the wrong wording... so even a point in the direction of the right wording would be much appreciated!

Thanks y'all

Comment: See these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is handled via database-driven solutions.  The "pages" are dynamic, and the URL is a parameter see @Konrad's comment that allows the pages to be looked up in a database which allows the dynamic content to be loaded into a single page which handles the complexity of each page seeming unique.